# AWS CLI: The config profile (test) could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am automating the AWS IAM user creation from Jenkins. We have multiple Accounts with programmatic access. I am trying to create user account for one account from CLI. It's working fine from CLI, but not from jenkins Pipeline.

Output through CLI

```
aws iam create-user --user-name --profile test tets

{
    "User": {
    "Path": "/",
    "UserName": "tets",
    "UserId": "AIDAXTRPYNIV6HK7XE43R",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::523012434475:user/tets",
    "CreateDate": "2019-09-18T06:49:41Z"
}



node
{
    stage ('creating IAM user'){
    sh 'aws iam create-user --user-name --profile test $Username'       
}
```

> The config profile (test) could not be found 
>   is the error i am getting from Jenkins Pipeline.

AWS CLI is configured on jenkins server. From ssh i am able to execute all the commands.

Comment: Did you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56632124/10846194
Also, if your Jenkins is on a Linux box, configure the aws profile for Jenkins user:
`sudo su – jenkins`
`aws configure`
Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-jenkins.html

Comment: Is your jenkins is run by the same user as your ssh user?

Comment: The same issue can be found in the below link. So just configure the cli profile for your Jenkins user and not ec2-user (Assuming) and you should be good. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=700690

Comment: No, how do i configure the same for Jenkins user?

Comment: Depends upon the host OS on which you are running Jenkins. If it's linux, then just switch to Jenkins user by typing `sudo su -jenkins` and then typing `aws configure` and entering the AK and SAK and if it's Windows then the first SO link I posted in my first comment should help.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I need to export the keys as variables to make this worked

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit this problem too.  Took an hour to unpick but FWIW in the interests of saving others' time (providing they have the same setup):

We use jenkins on an ec2 instance in AWS (built with "ubuntu" as the user).  The actual home dir for jenkins is mounted on /data/jenkins

ssh'ing on to the server as ubuntu user puts you in shell as ubuntu.
cd ~  # takes you to the home directory (you're already in)
pwd   # shows you in /home/ubuntu
sudo su -jenkins  # change to jenkins user
cd ~  # actually *still* takes you to /home/ubuntu
pwd   # prooves you're still in /home/ubuntu

Creating the .aws folder with config and credentials at this location means you can't use the --profile switch with aws cli commands in the pipeline.
The jenkins home dir is actually /data/jenkins so when the pipeline runs, calls to the aws cli will be looking for the .aws folder in /data/jenkins

Copying the .aws folder from /home/ubuntu to /data/jenkins, chowning objects for jenkins:jenkins and ensuring read perms (I used chmod 660) means that when the cli runs, it should see the config in /data/jenkins and the annoying "The config profile  could not be found"

Comment: Thanks for saving me a lot of time!